# Jquery: Get Body not descendant of iframe

Tags: google-chrome-extension, jquery-selectors, code-injection

I have an issue with a project of mine

I'm developing a chrome extension that injects html code into a page, specifically I'm injecting a bootstrap modal that's triggered by a browser action.

The issue I'm facing at the moment is that the code responsible for injecting the modal at the end of the `body` also injects it into any `iframes` present.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('html > body:not(iframe body)').append(container);
```

Sadly this does not result in selecting the intended body element. Since the code is injected, and I have no control over the source document, I cannot rely on `.first()` or `.last()` as a workaround

Any help with this issue would be appreciated :)

Edit:
Typically the problematic `iframes` are inside an element of type `#document` (i'd post an image of it if I had the required reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as myrsnipe mentioned if you want the script to only be injected into the top frame you have to set `"all_frames": false` in the manifest. I am writing this so it shows up as an answer, not just in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

try using `filter`

```
$('body').filter(function() {
    return !($(this).closest('iframe').length > 0);
}).append(container);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Yw8C2/)**

Comment: @myrsnipe.. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: It seems I was a bit too hasty accepting this answer, this does not work reliably afterall. It seems to be dependant on how the content of an `iframe` is laid out. I still appreciate the suggestion @Sushanth

Comment: I've re-accepted this answer as it does answer my question after all. My real issue was that I did not set the `"all_frames": false` flag in the manifest, thus injecting all of my code into iframes, not just the  html